# Use database as Custom_Storage with Libtorrent (Python)

Tags: python, database, libtorrent

I'm using Rasterbar libtorrent and want to use a MySQL Database as custom_storage. I know it can be done by implementing an own storage class that implements the storage_inferface (http://libtorrent.org/reference-Custom_Storage.html).
Did somenone already implement such a custom_storage in Python?

Related to:
[Keeping the downloaded torrent in memory rather than file libtorrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089806/keeping-the-downloaded-torrent-in-memory-rather-than-file-libtorrent)

Comment: I don't believe you can implement the storage interface in python.

Comment: Or maybe there is a C implementation with Python bindings?

Comment: the issue isn't that libtorrent is written in C++, it's that the storage_interface does not have a python binding

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 solutions:

1. Extend the python binding that comes with libtorrent to provide bindings for `storage_interface`. This is a kind of binding different from the existing ones, since it requires a *wrapper* type, that can bridge virtual function calls from C++ into a python subclass. Such wrappers are supported by boost.python, see [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.class_virtual_functions). This is also covered by an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054822/exposing-c-interface-in-boost-python).

   Once you've done that, you can implement a `storage_interface` in python.
2. Implement your storage in C++, and expose a function to python to use it. If you're in a position to use a patched libtorrent and you're comfortable with C++, I would expect this approach to be the most reliable, and simplest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not (yet) able to implement it. But I would be happy to use it.